# Custom generation of Model documentation using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle to generate swagger documentation for an ASP.NET core API I am writing. In my API, I am using a lot of custom Json converters, so the json I am receiving and returning doesn't look exactly like how the C# class is defined. For example, I may have a class like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private MyClass complicatedField;
}
```

which will be serialized as

```
{
    "complicatedField": "String representation of the object"
}
```

However, Swashbuckle documents it as

```
{
    "complicatedField": {/*Json object of all the fields MyClass has*/}
}
```

How do I tell Swashbuckle how my models get serialized and deserialized?

Comment: .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @ATerry .net core. I will add this to the question.

Comment: provided both answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `MapType` since you are changing the type to a primitive. Otherwise you would use a `SchemaFilter`.

**.Net Framework** call extension method somewhere at startup, ie. program.cs

```
httpConfiguration.EnableSwagger(c =>
      {
          c.MapType<MyClass>(() => new Schema { type = "string" }); // add additional schema info here
          // other configs
      });
```

**.Net Core** place in configure services method in startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
     {
          c.MapType<MyClass>(() => new Schema { Type = "string" });// add additional schema info here
          // other configs
     });
```